# Fill date (jj/mm/yyyy) only by entering the day (jj)

Tags: excel, vba, autofill, real-time-updates

I have 12 sheets for 12 months with random monthly dates to manually enter in column A. Let's take the month of January as an example:

When I enter the number ***25*** in cell A1, I'd like the cell to automatically return ***25/01/2019*** in A1 (!) (or 01/25/2019, as you like). Excel autofill features can't do that to my knowledge even with custom settings, so I guess : VBA ?

I think the code should look something like this (with change event):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Set rng = Range("A:A")
    If Not Application.Intersect(rng, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

           '???
           'If cell entered in range is a number Then
           'change value to "number" & "/01/2019" 

    End If
End Sub
```

That's where I am at. I'm pretty sure this could be a useful piece of code for people working with month and entering many dates. I'm I far from the truth ? Is it even do-able ? I understand it might be more complicated than it sounds.

Comment: Where should VBA find the year?

Comment: Could it be referenced from a given cell ? Something like "typed number" & "cell reference for month (eg. 1)" & "cell reference for year (eg. 2019)". I'm quite new to vba so besides the logic, I can't say if it's really achievable.

Comment: Did you just give up on [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55033639/9245853) to the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55032836/autofill-date-by-referring-only-one-number-with-excel-vba) you previously asked :) ?

Comment: Oh. I actually forgot I already posted about that!! You can see how much I have missed this feature. Indeed I couldn't figure out your answer due to my basic skills and could not overcome some errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Option Explicit    

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim AffectedRange As Range
    Set AffectedRange = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A:A"), Target)

    If Not AffectedRange Is Nothing Then
        Dim Cell As Range
        For Each Cell In AffectedRange.Cells
            If Cell.Value >= 1 And Cell.Value <= 31 Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                Cell.Value = DateSerial(2019, 1, Cell.Value)
                Cell.NumberFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next Cell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm sorry but aren't you hardcoding the month? shouldn't it take the month from the sheet index, name or whatever?

Comment: Impressive. I agree with @Damian, this could improve flexibility for users with different needs than mine, but it's a great start. Also, when I change another cell in the sheet, macro has an error at the line => If Not AffectedRange Then. Any idea why it's affecting range outside of "A:A" ?

Comment: If I can suggest one simplification - `Target.Parent` is the same as `Me`.

Comment: @Damian Yes, I hard coded the month, I thought the idea was pretty clear and the OP was pretty unclear about how the sheet was named. So I decided to leave it like that.

Comment: @Asger & Max Yes you are right, thanks. I was in a rush when posting it. I accepted the edit.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, of course that would make sense too ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
If Target.value2 > 0 and Target.value2 <= 31 Then
   Target.Value2 = dateSerial(year(now), month(now), Target.Value2)
End If
```